# Grep with regular expressions

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

Consider this text file:

```
TEST FILE : test                         #No match
                                         #No match
Run grep "1133*" on this file            #Match
                                         #No match
This line contains the number 113.       #Match
This line contains the number 13.        #No match
This line contains the number 133.       #No match
This line contains the number 1133.      #Match
This line contains the number 113312.    #Match
This line contains the number 1112.      #No match
This line contains the number 113312312. #Match
This line contains no numbers at all.    #No match
```

How does the `grep` command evaluate the `1133*` regular expression?

```
echo "Consider this text file:

TEST FILE : test                         #No match
                                         #No match
Run grep \"1133*\" on this file          #Match
                                         #No match
This line contains the number 113.       #Match
This line contains the number 13.        #No match
This line contains the number 133.       #No match
This line contains the number 1133.      #Match
This line contains the number 113312.    #Match
This line contains the number 1112.      #No match
This line contains the number 113312312. #Match
This line contains no numbers at all.    #No match" | grep "1133*"
```

Outputs:

```
Run grep "1133*" on this file            #Match
This line contains the number 113.       #Match
This line contains the number 1133.      #Match
This line contains the number 113312.    #Match
This line contains the number 113312312. #Match
```

Why is the line containing `113` a positive?

Is the regular expression `1133*` meant to mean anything else than
find all lines that contain the word `1133+anything else`?

This example was found on the [tldp regexp](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html) documentation page.

Comment: 1133\* matches 113 or 1133 or 11333 etc., or "zero or more occurrences of whatever element standing before \*".

Comment: You will get huge benefits out of learning the basics of regex (e.g. [here](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/)).

Comment: Lucian, can you share your grep command?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka It's quite hard to remember what went 8 years ago in my head, but for the sake of completeness I have updated my question to include the source as well as the regexp expression itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're thinking of a shell wildcard, where `*` matches anything. In [regular expressions](http://regular-expressions.info), a `*` is a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) that means "zero or more" of whatever immediately precedes it, which in this case is `3`.

So your expression means `113` followed by zero or more `3`s.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
grep "1133$" 
or 
grep "^1133$"

where ^ is the start of the line and $ is the end of the line

If your line was assuming 3 columns :
aaa 113 bbbb

cat file.txt|awk '{print $2}'|grep "^1133$"|wc -l

To ensure you are only looking at the specific column